# SERVICENOW - Populate a field whith result of query

Tags: servicenow

I recently tried to develop SNOW, so I need your help :-)

I created a Catalog Item and from the cmdb_ci_server table I extracted the list of operating systems [Type="Variable Lookup Select Box" and Name = os]; then I created a variable [Type="Reference" and Name = server] with the following Reference Qualifier "javascript: 'os =' + current.variables.os;".

At this point I need to automatically fill the field IP ADDRESS [Name = ip_address] with the value of the IP from cmdb_ci_server for the selected server.

I ask you how to do this and what is the type of variable to use for create the field ip_address [Single Line Text or others .....]

Thanks in advance,
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you could use a Catalog UI Policy with a condition which checks for when another field's value changes. And then in the script, set the value of the ip address field.

Also, there is a variable type for IP addresses.